# Mean Calculation for n items with Mean for 1 of such item

Tags: statistics, average, means

Below is an excerpt from the book [Database System Concepts, Seventh Edition](https://www.db-book.com/db7/), Chapter 12 - Storage Systems.

> Suppose that the mean time to failure of a disk is 100,000 hours, or
>   slightly over 11 years. Then, the mean time to failure of some disk in
>   an array of 100 disks will be 100,000∕100 = 1000 hours, or around 42
>   days, which is not long at all!

Is this calculation even right? If yes, Can someone please explain the math behind this?

Answer (score 1):

The failure of a device is often modeled with the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). If the time to failure of the $i$th disk is an exponential random variable with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda} = 100000$, then the [minimum of these $n=100$ independent exponential random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables) turns out to also be an exponential random variable with mean $\frac{1}{n\lambda} = 1000$.